# Digital Wallets on Events & Memberships Rationale

Tags: events, membership

For our own understanding when clients ask - why do we not offer digital wallets on events & memberships?

From a client perspective it feels disjointed that we offer it on fundraising, but not all pages so it would be good for us to understand technically to better communicate this.